# Magento 2 Release, is this the end of 1.9?

Tags: discussion, magento2

I take it that now Magento 2 has been released there will be no further development of the 1.x version apart from security updates.

What are your thoughts on the time frame required to upgrade from a typical 1.x store to Magento 2? Are you going to be looking at upgrade paths in 2016? 2017?

How long has Magento 1 got to live?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/54303/146 TL;DR: Magento 1.x will still be supported for 3 years after 2.0 comes out

Comment: @marius this is an answer ;)

Comment: it's kinda half an answer.

Comment: Magento has several time announced that they's support their platform at least for three years once M2 is released. Since EE uses CE as a core it only makes sense sense to make all those patches more or less universal (unless they fix EE specific stuff). This is also cheapest way to say that "we care", making people all warm and fuzzy about the platform. So it makes sense also from PR perspective.
 
What's altogether different thing is the meaning of word "supported". I expect occasional security patch and compatibility fix, but not much more.

Answer (score 3):

Magento is going to be supported 3 more years after v2 is out.